# Refer to different sheets from add in

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently working on a macro that modifies a standard format of spreadsheet. This will be used for many spreadsheets by several people in my company. So I've created an addin that everyone should be able to install and use.
However not all the spreadsheets will have the same name for each sheet.
Originally I tried referring to the sheets as

```
Sheet1.Range...
```

This gives

```
Run-time error '424':
Object required.
```

I can make it work with

```
Worksheets('name_of_worksheet').Range
```

But this requires the user to change that every time they wish to use the addin in a different spreadsheet, or to rename the sheets.
Is there another way of referencing the 'first' and 'second' worksheets? They will always be in that order and created in that order.

I believe this is to do with having saved the macro as an addin since I've never had this issue.

Thank you!

Edit:
The reformatting of the spreadsheet depends on data found in sheet 1 and sheet 2. So within the macro I need to be able to refer to both of those sheets. The name of the sheets will not always be the same, so I would rather not have to use:

```
Worksheets('name_of_worksheet').Range
```

Using Active Sheet is also not ideal since there will only be 1 active sheet, and I need to access both sheets.

```
Sheets(1).Range
```

does not work either, I get the error:

```
Run-time error '424':
Object required.
```

Comment: `Sheets(1).range` is as far as I know what you need. Or why not use ActiveSheet? That way it's the sheet the user has active right now

Comment: Tried that and it doesn't work. (sheets(1)) ActiveSheet does what I need for 1, but sheets 1 and 2 both need to be used.

Comment: I think you need to clarify the problem.

Comment: Is it clearer now?

Comment: I think it would be better if you use complete references, I mean, something like `TargetWorkbook.TargetWorksheet.Range...` Another option would be looping trough all sheets in the workbook, to get the names into an array, and call them.

Comment: I'll give that a go, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a ugly hack and loop two sheets.

```
i = 1
For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If i = 3 Then Exit For
    Debug.Print Sht.Name
    i = i + 1
Next Sht
```

This loops all sheets and when two sheets has been looped the code exits the for loop.
In the loop you could save the sheet names to variables or perhaps use this as the base of your code and add your code instead of the debug line.